# every differentiable function $f;\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

This question is taken out of the text book High Dimensional Probability by Roman. I am unsure from the context if it means locally or globally Lipschitz. But the question is as follows:

Every differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ is Lipschitz, and

$\|f\|_{Lip}\le{∥∇f∥_∞}$ .

I have shown that if a function is continuously differentiable, it is locally Lipchitz. But since the question uses $\|f\|_{Lip}$ I believe I am to show that if a function is only differentiable, it is globally Lipchitz.

Any hints / clues?

Comment: A differentiable function may not be Lipschitz, i.e. $x \mapsto e^x$.

Comment: Can a differentiable function be at least locally Lipschitz?

Comment: If it is continuously differentiable then yes, since the gradient will be bounded on any compact set

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch In the case $f$ is continuously differentiable, and hence locally Lipschitz. what is the meaning/definition of $\|f\|_{Lip}$?

Comment: The function $\ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ $ defined by
$$
f(x)=\cases{0& if $\ x=0$\\
x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)&if $\ x\ne0$}
$$
is everywhere differentiable, but not locally Lipschitz in any neighbourhood of $\ x=0\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera  In the case  is continuously differentiable, and hence locally Lipschitz. what is the meaning/definition of $\|f\|_{Lip}$?

Comment: @kam The Lipschitz norm is the smallest possible Lipschitz constant

Comment: @kam Is $\Vert f \Vert_{Lip}$ not defined in the book you mentioned? If not, I won't be at ease ready such a book...

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Can the inequality be shown over one of the neighborhoods of a point (given that the function is continuously differentiable) in the locally Lipschitz case? if so, how?

Comment: @kam If $f$ is continuously differentiable, it is indeed locally Lipschitz. This is a direct consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net What I am asking is if a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ is continuously differentiable it it is locally Lipschitz. My question is, can it be shown that $\|f\|_{Lip}\le{\|\Nabla{}f\|_{\infty}}$ on some neighboured of a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you know Mean value Theorem?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I do, but can't see how this would work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roman Vershynin has made the final draft of his book *High-Dimensional Probability* freely downloadable from [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html) (click on the link labelled "Your Copy" on the left side of the page).

I don't believe the statement of exercise $5.1.2$(b) on p.$106$ is correct as given.  It should read:

"Every differentiable function $\ f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ *with bounded gradient* is Lipschitz, and
$$
\|f\|_\text{Lip}\le \sup_\limits{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|\nabla f(x)\|_2."
$$
As indicated by [mathcounterexamples.net](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187663/mathcounterexamples-net) in the comments, this version of the statement can be proved by appealing to the
[mean-value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables):
\begin{align}
\left|f\left(x_2\right)-f\left(x_1\right)\right|&=\left|\left\langle\nabla f\left(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2\right),x_2-x_1\right\rangle\right|\\
&\hspace{4em}\text{for some }\lambda\in(0,1)\\
&\le \left\| \nabla f\left(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda\right)x_2)\right\|\,\left\|x_2-x_1\right\|\\
&\le \sup_\limits{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|\nabla f(x)\| \left\|x_2-x_1\right\|\ .
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not true that every differentiable function is Lipschitz, or even locally Lipschitz.

For example, $$f(x) = \cases{x^2 \cos(1/x^2) & if $x \ne 0$\cr
0 & if $x = 0$}$$ is differentiable but not continuously differentiable,
and $f'$ is unbounded near $0$; $f$ is not Lipschitz in any interval containing $0$, as  e.g. 
$$ \left|\frac{f(1/\sqrt{k\pi}) - f(1/\sqrt{(k+1)\pi})}{1/\sqrt{k\pi} - 1/\sqrt{(k+1)\pi}}\right| \sim \text{const}\cdot k^{1/2} $$

Comment: You probably meant ...$\cos$... instead of $\sin$ as everything vanish for $\sin$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, thanks for catching that.